# Joomla JUser getinstance Questions

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla1.5

I am attempting to make an authentication plugin. `JUser::getInstance()` takes one input, and it is supposed to be the id. Is there any way to get an instance of a User using some other indentifier? such as username, email etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there isnt any such method. But yes if you are sure that username or email are unique then you can modify your file user.php in libraries/joomla/user/ and add a method there.

```
getInstanceByEmail($email)
{
     $query = "select id from jos_users where email=".email;
     // use the code to get the id;
    return getInstance($id);
} // this is just a sample code of how it can be achieved
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of that  >.>

Answer (score 0):

Since Joomla's own authentication is done by checking the user's username (and password of course), it has to be unique. And yes you can do something like what @Rixius suggested.

Here's my version:

```
    // Get a database object
    $db     = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select('id, password');
    $query->from('#__users');
    $query->where('username=' . $db->Quote($credentials['username']));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadObject();
    $user = JFactory::getUser();

    if ($result)
    {
        $user = JUser::getInstance($result->id);
    }
```